# Auth0 in react (+ts+vite) not authenticating - stuck on loading

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, auth0

this is my first time working with react/Auth0 and I cannot find the reason for this issue. Maybe someone can help.

Auth0 is imported, domain and ID defined, properties (isauthenticated, isLoading and LoginWithDirect) imported as well.

For testing I also have a login and a logout button.

Content is wrapped in:

```
<Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      authorizationParams={{
        redirect_uri: "/callback",
      }}
    >
```

with:

```
<Route path="/callback" element={<Callback />} />
```

When I click the login button, it redirects to the Auth0 interface and after successful login back to /callback.

Printing `isLoading` and `isAuthenticated` to the console, `isLoading = true; isAuthenticated = false`

When I integrate an automatic redirect:
In App.tsx I use:

```
    if (!isAuthenticated && !isLoading) {
    
    loginWithRedirect();
        return null;
      }
    
    if (isLoading) {
        return <p>Loading...</p>;
      }
```

the page only shows "Loading..."

Where could I look for troubleshooting? Link settings all seem to be correct. I followed the instructions, do I need to do something else in my app? When being redirected to my app, it shows a key in the URL that disappears after 2-3 seconds, is my App meant to somehow grab that information? Do I have to resolve it with Routing?

Thanks a lot for your help :)